# Search and place text at end of file

Tags: unix

How to place the text at end of the file unix.

For example, i have a file file.txt

```
Second
Last
Fourth
```

I have a requirement like, i have to search for text(for example last in this case) and place it at end of the file.

After this  file should be

```
Second
Fourth
Last
```

I am new to unix and someone please help me the steps.

Answer (score 0):

One way, using `ed`:

```
ed -s file.txt <<EOF
/Last/m$
w
EOF
```

The `ed` commands in the heredoc mean: Take the first line in the file containing `Last`, **m**ove it to the end, and then **w**rite the file back to disc.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the word you have to search for is "`Second`" and is specified by the variable "`word`".

```
$ cat last.txt 
OSeconder
SecondTime
Fourth
Last
Second
Third

$ word="Second"; sed -i ""   "/^$word$/d"   last.txt; echo $word >> last.txt 

$ cat last.txt 
OSeconder
SecondTime
Fourth
Last
Third
Second
```

Here:

```
sed:
  -i => in place editing, change the file in place. On Linux you do not have to give "" after this argument but on Mac you do.

  /^$word$/d => delete the line beginning and ending with "$word"

And echo the "word" to the end of the file.
```

If you would like to see how the simple regex goes to work, check this link: https://regex101.com/r/mDxE8q/1

Comment: If you have both `Second` and `SecondTime`, it will delete both. Probably need `"/^$word$/d"` or some such.